# Is "grossingly" a word?

Tags: word-usage

Is grossingly a word? If not what's the closest alternative? Example sentence:

> The grumpy man stared at the couple, who were being **grossingly** sweet to each other.

Comment: Did you bother to check a dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I’ve never encountered any references that suggest that *grossingly* can be viewed as a legitimate construction. In every similar context to your proposed use that I’ve seen, either *sickeningly* or *disgustingly* has been used.

I’m guessing that you derived your example from the phrase *gross out*, which is slang for *disgust* (as used as a verb), with some intensification that normally can’t easily be expressed.

Comment: I'm sure you're right that OP's example is a (failed?) attempt to "adverbialize" the phrasal verb ***to gross out***. As a native speaker I probably wouldn't even attempt to do that, but it seems to me you could (almost?) get away with it so long as you retain the preposition. So even though ***gross-outingly sweet behaviour*** looks pretty awkward, it's at least syntactically credible.

Comment: ... apropos which I just found this reference to [*despite stats about **throw-uppingly** high tuition and the  sometimes inferior teaching-abilities of professors.*](https://www.quora.com/Do-schools-like-NYU-Tufts-and-Washington-University-have-less-extremely-high-intelligence-people-than-state-schools) Where the writer is clearly a competent articulate native speaker, even though it looks like he's missed out the word ***fees*** after ***tuition***. So the short answer for OP here is "Don't try this at home" (but if you *must*, at least preserve the preposition! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Are you a native speaker of English? You keep making comments about omitted words and non-obvious grammar errors that directly contradict the common actual usages you're commenting on - in this particular case, omitting _fees_ after _tuition_ is so common that many people will think that including it is wrong and redundant. I also question the competence of the author of that sentence; _teaching abilities_ should _not_ be hyphenated.

Comment: Sure I'm a native speaker - with a degree in English Language & Literature, as it happens. It's only my personal opinion, obviously, but I'd say relatively speaking I'm a very *competent* native speaker. And that's not because I study schoolboy grammar carefully; it's because I have a careful ear for what people (including well-respected writers) might actually say or write in areas where simple rules simply don't allow us to easily / "correctly" express ourselves as concisely and accurately as we might like.

Comment: The "tuition (fees)" issue might be a US/UK difference--in the US, "tuition" virtually always means "fees paid for schooling" rather than the schooling itself, which I believe is the main definition in the UK. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tuition)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Things like "throw-uppingly" are classic nonce words, which in the case of "throw-uppingly" have found somewhat more widespread (>1 occasion) usage because people find them funny in the similar vein that people use "Long time no see". Learners should not be encouraged to coin similar things because they have no (or limited) feel for language, and their nonce words will not find acceptance in the same way that a quirk of a competent English writer would. I see a repeated theme of extreme linguistic laissez-faire in your contributions, and I don't find this helpful for learners.

Comment: @tenebris2020: It would be trivial for the OP here to have established that ***grossingly*** isn't a "word", simply by noting that it's not in any dictionaries, and written instances are virtually non-existent. I think one of my roles here is to give learners a sense of how native speakers approach such usages (information which they *can't* easily find in online resources. What you call my "extreme linguistic laissez-faire" attitude simply reflects the fact that my academic background (& temperament) is more rooted in "descriptive linguistics" than "prescriptive grammar" (because I'm a Brit?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "how native speakers approach" — there is a difference between how native speakers approach something and how native speakers with degrees in their native philology do. I think learners here deserve at least a clear disclaimer wherever answers (or, rather, comments under the quesion—which have now been deleted by someone) are _too_ non-trivial (and I would definitely put coining nonce words in the category of "_too_ non-trivial"). My attitude here reflects the experience of actually teaching foreign languages in real life which involves more feedback than "accepting an answer."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, what we are dealing with here in the case of these "non-trivial approaches" is not _describing_ language as it is. It is **constructing** something that does not exist in language as it is, according to some rules (and reasoning about which rules might be applicable). So no, it's not descriptive linguistics (which is _limited_ by what is _actually there_). And while language develops by native speakers constantly constructing smth new, it's never developed by what is constructed by learners of language. "All your base are belong to us" is forever a meme,not a language unit

Comment: @tenebris2020: Well, you've obviously "won" your point, in that the mods have deleted comments I made against the question itself. In which I recall mentioning that the "syntactically correct" word is in fact ***grossly***, but that ***this subtly changes the meaning***. That suggestion has subsequently been posted as a formal answer, and currently has more upvotes than Jeff's here (which I did upvote, obviously). I don't have to agree with your perspective, but in the circumstances there's not much point in me arguing with you.

Answer (score 14):

The correct term is *grossly*.

> 3. In a disgusting or coarse manner; vulgarly.
>
>    *‘do you have one cookie, or grossly eat the whole package?’*

-- Oxford Dictionaries

However, this word is not often used in this sense (or at least I haven't heard it being used like this very often), so I would choose *disgustingly* or something similar.

Comment: Straightforward and accurate. I don't find the choice of using grossly in the OP's sample sentence to be awkward or unusual at all.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at *disgustingly*:

- Disgust - a word that means "to make sick, typically through senses."  You might say *This disgusts me.*
- Disgusting - while it's possible to say something like *Disgusting me terribly, I left the trash dump*, this particular 
  "-ing" word is common to use as a modifier or copular subject complement.  *The disgusting trash dump was abhorrent*, *I found her hair disgusting*.
- You can typically add *-ly* to words that modify nouns to turn them into words that modify verbs.  Hence, *disgustingly*: *That cat disgustingly ate the roadkill in the street.*

Now, let's take *gross*:

- *Gross* has two meanings.  One is "to have a profit of X after doing something, especially working a job for a time" - *I grossed 20,000 dollars last year*.
- The other meaning is *to be disgusting*.  *This is gross*.
- Gross as a verb does NOT mean *to be disgusting* - there is the phrasal variation *gross out* that does work that way though.  *This grosses me out*.
- Because *gross (meaning disgusting)* isn't really a verb, deriving a gerund/participle from it doesn't work too well.  *Grossing me terribly, I left the trash drump* (fails) - but *Grossing me out terribly, I left the trash dump*
  (does mostly work).
- *Grossing* would not be one of those *-ing* words that works to modify a noun.  *I tried to avoid the grossing trash heap* (sounds like the "profit" meaning of *gross* is trying to be intended and that the trash heap is becoming bigger).

  You can't use *gross out* in this way either.  *I tried to avoid the grossing out trash heap* (sounds like you are trying to say "I tried to avoid grossing out the trash heap").
- Thus *grossingly* doesn't technically work.

However ...

At least the region and time I grew up in within the US, the idea of things being called *gross* is something children that are not yet teenagers do.  Especially with respect to young boys and their stereotypical thoughts of young girls (cooties and all that). "Boys think kissing girls is 'gross'" type of thing.

So *grossingly* could invoke that type of thought in respect to someone else's PDA, and if that's what the writer is trying to convey, it's a well-chosen "intentional twist" of the language.

But don't try using that term unless you are a professional writer or trying to convey that type of thought/impression/mood, etc.

Comment: "Gross" has many more meanings than two - for example, "before tax", or "one hundred and forty four".

Answer (score 2):

In the specific context, you could use "cloyingly"

> [Cloying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloying)
>   adjective
>   disgusting or distasteful by reason of excess cloying sweetness;
>   also : excessively sweet or sentimental. e.g. a cloying romantic comedy
>   — cloyingly adverb